# Where can i find information on creating plugins for SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssms

I have read that while plug-ins are not supported for SQL Server Management Studio, it can be done.

Does anyone have any resources or advice on how to go about it using C#?

A company that is currently offering plug-ins to Management Studio is Red Gate:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Refactor/index.htm

Comment: If you want to roll your own, check out [The Black Art of Writing a SQL Server Management Studio 2005 Add-In](http://jcooney.net/archive/2007/11/26/55358.aspx)

Comment: I don't know why these types of question are not allowed.  "Because they don't fit our format perfectly" is a lame reason.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

[Here's a list](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/11/20/Free-SQL-Server-tools-that-might-make-your-life-a.aspx) of a lot of free tools for sql server. at the top you have the section that holds stuff about add-ins from SSMS.

You might also want to check out [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) which is an add-in I made. It's free but not open sourced.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  This definitely put me on the right track.

Comment: Question clearly asks: "Does anyone have any resources or advice on how to go about it using C#?". You don't answer the question at all.

Comment: Agreed - I was looking for the answer to the same question, but didn't find it here.

Comment: The SSMS Tools Pack is no longer free.

Comment: Not answering the question

Answer (score 26):

Here is a very good guide to creating a plugin for SQL Server Management Studio:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/07/28/how-to-create-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx

Basically, it consists of the following:

1. Create a Visual Studio add-in with certain settings.
2. Subscribe to SSMS specific events
3. Code

The article includes a nice sample that you can use to skip some of the manual steps.